# How to Update Resources for already deployed AWS Resources in Serverless Framework?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Like the title, I want to update or edit some configurations my DynamoDB table which is already deployed to AWS. I am currently managing all resources in one serverelss.yml file. When I change some configuration of the table and try to deploy through Serverless framework, the error is

`CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename "Test Dynamo Table" and update the stack again.`

The only way I found is create new database with updated configuration, migrate to that new database and delete the old database manually (through AWS Console).
Or maybe another way might be creating AWS resources in separate serverless.yml, so I don't have to remove and re-create all resources every time. I can remove only the specific resource.

But wonder is there anyway I can solve this issue through Serverless framework or some other IaC tool? I just wonder what is some programatic way to update the existing resources.

Currently, what I typically did was run `sls remove` and redo `sls deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely you are updating something that is not supported, such as changing partition or sort key of a table or index.

This isn't a limitation on serverless but rather that of DynamoDB.

> CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename "Test Dynamo Table" and update the stack again

As such the exception you receive is telling you that if you want to update the table, it must be replaced. And that is why you see success while creating a new one.